# Firebase Cloud Function problem - promises related

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

I have a problem with a callable firebase cloud function (**exports.listAllUsers**).

**Backend:** Nodejs & Firebase-Cloud_functions to use **admin.auth().listUsers**
**Problem:** Result (usersList; an array with the uid of the users) is OK in cloud-functions-emulator (log) but NOT in the client (console.log(usersList) in browser is null)
**Maybe a problem related with...:** bad understanding of promises. A second code example is working with async/await but not working with .then().

The code of the function **listAllUsers** is basically  copy&paste from docs (original code snipet: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users). My code modifications are 5 (comments in the code), to get a list of users uid:

```js
    exports.listAllUsers = functions.https.onCall(() => { // -1) callable function
      const usersList = ['12323211'] // ----------------------2) first user uid, just a sample
      function listAllUsers (nextPageToken) {
        // List batch of users, 1000 at a time.
        admin.auth().listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
          .then((listUsersResult) => {
            listUsersResult.users.forEach((userRecord) => {
              usersList.push(userRecord.uid) // --------------3) get users uids
            })
            if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
              // List next batch of users.
              listAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken)
            }
            console.log(usersList) //-------------------------4) list users uid (cloud functions console)
            return usersList //-------------------------------5) return to the client the same as showed at the console
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error listing users:', error)
            return null
          })
      }
      // Start listing users from the beginning, 1000 at a time.
      listAllUsers()
    })
```

The method in the client is...

```
getUsersList: async function (userType) {
      const usersList = await this.$fb.functions().httpsCallable('listAllUsers')()
      console.log('usersList: ', usersList)
    }
```

I am using firebase emulators. Cloud functions log is OK, you can see the sample uid and the other uids:

[cloud function emulator console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIHYW.png)

But I don't get the same in the client:

[client console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkop3.png)

I think I am doing something wrong related with promises... because a simplification of the code is working with async/await:

```js
    exports.listAllUsers = functions.https.onCall(async () => {
      try {
        listUsersResult = await admin.auth().listUsers()
        return listUsersResult
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error listing users:', error)
        return null
      }
    })
```

[Browser console output (reduced code with async/await)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JbRx.png)

But the same is not working with then()...

```js
    exports.listAllUsers = functions.https.onCall(() => {
      admin.auth().listUsers()
        .then((listUsersResult) => {
          return listUsersResult
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('Error listing users:', error)
          return null
        })
    })
```

[Browser console output (reduced code with .then())](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdb88.png)

I can refactor the initial snipet of code with async/await, but I am interested in the solution with the original code (.then() flavor; I always use async/await because I am quite new at js)... Anyone can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because with the `async/await` version you correctly return `listUsersResult` by doing

```
    listUsersResult = await admin.auth().listUsers()
    return listUsersResult
```

but, with the `then` version, you don't. You should return the entire promises chain, as follows:

```
exports.listAllUsers = functions.https.onCall(() => {
  return admin.auth().listUsers()   // !!! Note the return here  !!!
    .then((listUsersResult) => {
      return listUsersResult
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error listing users:', error)
      return null
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I decided to code an `async/await` version for my cloud function. The `then` version in the first code snipet requires more than just adding the `return` to the entire promises chain (it initially complains because of the recursivity, maybe, asking me to add `async`to the wrapper function `listAllUsers`... I'd like the `then` version to just copy&paste from the firebase docs, but it wanted more).

I'd like to share this homemade (but initially tested) version as **a sample with async/await without recursivity** to list users with `admin.auth().listUsers(maxResults?, pageToken?)`:

```js
// get list of users
exports.listAllUsers = functions.https.onCall(async () => {
  const usersList = []
  try {
    let listUsersResult
    let nextPageToken
    do {
      if (listUsersResult) {
        nextPageToken = listUsersResult.pageToken
      }
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
      listUsersResult = await admin.auth().listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
      listUsersResult.users.forEach((userRecord) => {
        usersList.push(userRecord.uid)
      })
    } while (listUsersResult.pageToken)
    return usersList
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error listing users:', error)
    return null
  }
})
```